# How to authenticate my Picasaweb Albums App with Oauth2

Tags: java, exception, oauth-2.0, google-data-api, google-photos

So I followed this tutorial to make a basic Picasawebalbums Api app. I got the tutorial here https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java

I had problems described here [Create PicasawebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617386/create-picasawebservice) and here [Error while using PicasawebService with GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320768/error-while-using-picasawebservice-with-gae) and here [upload image to Picasa using picasawebservice in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418750/upload-image-to-picasa-using-picasawebservice-in-android)

I solved the classNotFoundException and now have an authenticationException. I found some questions about that but none of them helped.

stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:688)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:397)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:364)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:319)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:303)
at duh.Test.main(Test.java:37)
```

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ServiceException, AuthenticationException{

    PicasawebService myService = new PicasawebService(APP_NAME);

    myService.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    myService.setReadTimeout(60000);

    myService.setUserCredentials(EMAIL, PASSWORD);

    URL feedUrl = new URL("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/samdup123?kind=album");

    UserFeed myUserFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, UserFeed.class);

    for(AlbumEntry myAlbum : myUserFeed.getAlbumEntries()){
        System.out.println(myAlbum.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }

}
```

}

And my imports

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.photos.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.photos.PicasawebService;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.photos.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;
```

Line 37 from the stack trace points to `myService.setUserCredentials(EMAIL, PASSWORD);`

It seems like I need to drop this code entirely and use OAuth2 to get authenticated. I have read about that but it is very complicated reading and I have no idea what to use for my application. I found this code

```
SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

    File p12 = new File("D:\\cgi\\RemedyClientTest\\src\\main\\resources\\RemedyClient-b04b4c2d956c.p12");

    factory = FeedURLFactory.getDefault();

    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
       String [] SCOPESArray= {"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full", "https://docs.google.com/feeds"};
       final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);
       GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
         .setTransport(httpTransport)
         .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
         .setServiceAccountId("1088335521358-ijasu5h7kauqbja6hih91l2c23amv7ft@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
         .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
         .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
         .build();

    service = new SpreadsheetService("Main");

    service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

But I don't know how to 'translate' that to PicasawebAlbums. I have tried but fell short because I have no idea what jar files to import.

Am i right to assume that my problem is that I need to use Oauth2? Is there anything else I should use? If someone has a working application can you show me all of the imports you have because some of mine seem to be outdated and replaced by others and its all very confusing.